# Constraints in a Mean-Variance Optimization Case

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, optimization, sharpe-ratio

Might be a repeat question, feel free to close if it is.

I am trying to perform a mean-variance optimization (maximizing the Sharpe ratio) for lets say 5 assets. Besides the weights of the assets summing up to 1, what other constraints is necessary?

Because currently when I perform my optimization, I notice there are cases where my weights do sum to 1, but some of the weights just blow up. For example it could be like [-9000,9001,0,0,0], which causes the returns to explode and is not too realistic. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is why some people like to put a no-short selling constraint, to avoid this kind of blow up. It occurs for ex when two assets are highly correlated, so the algorithm decides to short the less performing of the two assets to allow a bigger investment in the higher return one. The algorithm sees a quasi-arbitrage situation between 2 similar assets and tries to take advantage of it (but it is more likely to be just bad input data). This much is well known.

Comment: Hi @nbbo2, thanks for your answer. I wish I could tag yours as the correct solution to this query. I was surprised initially because before when I tried to replicate portfolio optimization papers they included the no-short selling constraints as a portfolio variant. It is good to know that I am currently on the right track. I would most probably look into the window I used to calibrate my covariance matrix. It might have been too short...

Comment: @Kai At university (and most textbooks), the general problem is to construct a portfolio using MV-optimisation where short-selling isn't allowed. If you want to allow short-selling in your problem, just take the opposite where you have to construct a portfolio and you are only allowed to short-sell. Then analyse the difference between the portfolios.

Comment: I'd like to add that often when using the mean variance framework the covariance matrix is optimized in such a way that that the eigenvalues does not get close to zero to avoid blowing up. One way is to use [shrinkage](http://www.ledoit.net/honey.pdf).

Comment: Hi @Xiarpedia, I don't quite understand your comment. Because in a mean-variance framework, the weights are ones being optimized/iterated through possible values. Unless you are talking about shrinkage, which is where there is a "1st-stage" optimization for the covariance matrix, then a "2nd-stage" optimization for the weights. What do you mean by your comments on the eigenvalues?